# How to solve the following equation $\sqrt[3]{x+3}+\sqrt[3]{x}=\sqrt[3]{3+8x}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, radicals

I am trying to solve this equation:
$$\sqrt[3]{x+3}+\sqrt[3]{x}=\sqrt[3]{3+8x}$$
I would like to get some advice, how to solve it. 
Thanks.

Comment: The Maple code $$with(RealDomain): solve((x+3)^{1/3}+x^{1/3}-(3+8*x)^{1/3}, [x]) $$ outputs $$[[x=0],[x=-1/3]]

 .$$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First note that $x=0$ is a solution. Now we consider $x\neq 0$ and we divide by $\sqrt[3]{x}$. We get $\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{3}{x}}+1=\sqrt[3]{8+\frac{3}{x}}$, so lets define $y=\frac{3}{x}$ and write
$$1+\sqrt[3]{1+y} = \sqrt[3]{8+y}.$$
Now we cube both sides to obtain
$$1+3\sqrt[3]{1+y}+3\sqrt[3]{1+y}^2+1+y = 8+y$$
or
$$\sqrt[3]{1+y}+\sqrt[3]{1+y}^2 = 2.$$
We complete the square to obtain
$$\left(\sqrt[3]{1+y}+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{9}{4}$$
or
$$\sqrt[3]{1+y} = \frac{-1\pm 3}{2}.$$
Hence $y = 0$ or $y=-9$.
There is no $x$ corresponding to $y=0$, but corresponding to $y=-9$ we have $x=-\frac{1}{3}$.
Concluding, $x\in\left\{-\frac{1}{3},0\right\}$.

Comment: Wouldn't the same method work by just cubing at the very start?

Comment: @DepeHb Possibly. I just dislike having stray $\sqrt[3]{x}$'s hanging around ;)

Answer (score 1):

W'll use $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2.$$
Since $x+3=x=-3-8x$ is impossible, our equation is equivalent to
$$x+3+x-3-8x+3\sqrt[3]{x(x+3)(8x+3)}=0$$ or
$$\sqrt[3]{x(x+3)(8x+3)}=2x$$ or
$$x((x+3)(8x+3)-8x^2)=0,$$ 
which gives $x=0$ or $x=-\frac{1}{3}$.